# Dirty and check if email attribute changed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Last part of my project, Hopefully.

Need to check if user.email attribute changes.  If it does, then need to tell mailchimp to change or add the email.

Looks like Dirty will do this, but have never used it before.  How can I catch the change in a block, or pass it to a block, and then update the attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using Rails Dirty methods:

```
if @user.email.changed?
  # ...
end
```

But you can also do:

```
if @user.email != params[:user][:email]
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 11):

Using the [ActiveRecord::Dirty](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Dirty.html) module is pretty straightforward:

```
bob = User.find_by_email('bob@example.org')
bob.changed?       # => false

bob.email = 'robert@example.org')
bob.changed?       # => true
bob.email_changed? # => true
bob.email_was      # => 'bob@example.org'
bob.email_change   # => ['bob@example.org', 'robert@example.org']
bob.changed        # => ['email']
bob.changes        # => { 'email' => ['bob@example.org', 'robert@example.org'] }
```

Comment: Saw the API, but can't get it to work.  I assume you have to include the Dirty class, but can't find how to do it.  At the moment "if @user.email_changed?"

Comment: The Dirty module is included by default. Are you getting an error message?

Comment: Not getting an error but its not detecting the change.  If I try Dorian's recommendation it does see the change.

Comment: Are you saving the record before trying to see the change? Saving resets the dirty state.

Comment: "if @user.email_changed?" is in update but before "if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])".  Should it be else where?  before_filter?

Comment: Nice answer, I did not know it, very nice.